# Difference between ".class" and "* html .class" and "html>body .class"

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've studied css styles of Google Docs, and I have noticed there such a thing:

```
.goog-inline-block {
    position        : relative;
    display         : -moz-inline-box;
    display         : inline-block
}

* html .goog-inline-block {
    display         : inline
}

*:first-child + html .goog-inline-block {
    display         : inline
}

html>body .goog-inline-block {
    display         : -moz-inline-box;
    display         : inline-block
}
```

I understand what this `.goog-inline-block` class should mean, but this code arose questions for me:

- Why are there so much declarations for a simple class?
- Why does simple `.class-name` declaration differ from `* html .class-name` declaration?
- What is this crafty construction `*:first-child + html .class-name` doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This rule:

```
* html .goog-inline-block {
    display         : inline
}
```

defines a style for IE6. In IE6's document model, there's a mysterious root element that contains `html`, so this selector takes advantage of that fact using the `* html` hack.

This rule:

```
*:first-child + html .goog-inline-block {
    display         : inline
}
```

defines a style for IE7. In IE7's document model, there's no more root element *above* `html`, but there's another one *before* it, which is what's targeted by the `*:first-child + html` selector.

This rule:

```
html>body .goog-inline-block {
    display         : -moz-inline-box;
    display         : inline-block
}
```

defines styles for IE7+ and other browsers. The child selector `>` isn't supported by IE6, so it never sees this rule. `-moz-inline-box` is actually the same as `inline-block`, but meant for Firefox 2 and older as those versions don't support `inline-block`.

There are so many declarations for that class because different browsers have problems with the `display: inline-block` style, so hacks and workarounds are needed for these browsers.

Comment: So, `.class-name { display: inline; }` isn't crossbrowser, is it? I can admit that IE6 needs exceptions, but do other browsers too?

Comment: @Innuendo: The cross-browser issue doesn't lie in `.class-name`, but in `display: -moz-inline-box` and `display: inline-block`.

Comment: Sorry for `* :first-child` - I've removed space (it's because of manually beautifying that code). Ok, so issue is exactly in `display: inline-block` property, but not in `.class-name` - I've understood, thanks